# How to say 'fleshed out' as in 'complete'

Tags: english-to-japanese

If I want to say: "You should read the book. The story is more fleshed out", can I say

> 本を読んだほうがいいです。話はより肉付けされるんです。

Comment: I suppose you mean 'the book version' as opposed to some adaptation of it. Either way some more contexts would help. Or you can try [英辞郎](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=flesh+out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost correct. Just change 「肉付けされる」to「肉付けされている」for grammar. 「される」implies that the story will be more fleshed out (as in it is not fleshed out now). 「されている」fixes this.